# Angular2 - error TS2300: Duplicate identifier 'PromiseConstructor'

Tags: angularjs, angular

In my main.ts, I include the workaround following https://github.com/angular/angular/blob/master/CHANGELOG.md

```
    ///<reference path="../../../node_modules/angular2/typings/browser.d.ts"/>

import {bootstrap} from '../../../node_modules/angular2/platform/browser'
import {AppComponent} from './app.component'
// Add all operators to Observable
import 'rxjs/Rx'

bootstrap(AppComponent);
```

And in tsconfig.json, browser.d.ts and browser are excluded.

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "target": "es5",
    "module": "system",
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "sourceMap": true,
    "emitDecoratorMetadata": true,
    "experimentalDecorators": true,
    "removeComments": false,
    "noImplicitAny": false
  },
  "exclude": [
              "typings/browser.d.ts",
              "typings/browser",
              "node_modules"
            ]
}
```

In my index.html's head

```
 app.use('/scripts', express.static(__dirname + '/node_modules'));

       <!-- 1. Load libraries -->
    <!-- IE required polyfills, in this exact order -->
    <script src="/scripts/es6-shim/es6-shim.min.js"></script>
    <script src="/scripts/systemjs/dist/system-polyfills.js"></script>
    <script src="/scripts/angular2/es6/dev/src/testing/shims_for_IE.js"></script>   
    <script src="/scripts/angular2/bundles/angular2-polyfills.js"></script>
    <script src="/scripts/systemjs/dist/system.src.js"></script>
    <script src="/scripts/rxjs/bundles/Rx.js"></script>
    <script src="/scripts/angular2/bundles/angular2.dev.js"></script>
    <!-- 2. Configure SystemJS -->
    <script>
      System.config({
        packages: {        
          app: {
            format: 'register',
            defaultExtension: 'js'
          }
        }
      });
      System.import('../js/acApp/main.ts')
            .then(null, console.error.bind(console));
    </script>
```

package.json

```
{
  "name": "AC",
  "version": "0.0.1",
  "private": true,
  "scripts": {
        "start": "concurrently \"npm run tsc:w\" \"nodemon server.js\" ",
        "tsc": "tsc",
        "tsc:w": "tsc -w",
        "lite": "lite-server",
        "typings": "typings",
        "postinstall": "typings install"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "bcrypt-nodejs": "*",
    "body-parser": "*",
    "cookie-parser": "*",
    "ejs": "*",
    "errorhandler": "*",
    "express": "4.x",
    "express-json": "*",
    "express-session": "*",
    "method-override": "*",
    "morgan": "*",
    "mysql": "*",
    "nodemon": "^1.9.1",
    "passport": "*",
    "passport-local": "*",
    "serve-favicon": "*",
    "bcrypt":"*",
    "cookie-parser":"*",
    "express-session":"*",
    "bookshelf":"*",
    "passport": "*",
    "passport-local": "*",
    "knex":"*",
    "log4js":"*",
    "express-session":"*",
    "angular2": "*",
    "traceur":"*",
    "systemjs": "*",
    "es6-promise": "*",
    "es6-shim": "^0.35.0",

    "reflect-metadata": "0.1.2",

    "rxjs": "5.0.0-beta.2",

    "zone.js": "^0.6.4" 

  },
  "devDependencies": {
        "concurrently": "^2.0.0",
        "lite-server": "^2.1.0",
        "typescript": "^1.8.9",
        "typings":"^0.7.9"
  }
}
```

But I have still got the duplicate errors. Any idea?

```
[0] 16:47:12 - File change detected. Starting incremental compilation...
[0] node_modules/angular2/typings/browser.d.ts(6,14): error TS2300: Duplicate identifier 'PromiseConstructor'.
[0] node_modules/angular2/typings/es6-collections/es6-collections.d.ts(22,5): error TS2300: Duplicate identifier 'done'.
[0] node_modules/angular2/typings/es6-collections/es6-collections.d.ts(23,5): error TS2300: Duplicate identifier 'value'.
[0] node_modules/angular2/typings/es6-collections/es6-collections.d.ts(46,5): error TS2300: Duplicate identifier 'size'.
[0] node_modules/angular2/typings/es6-collections/es6-collections.d.ts(52,5): error TS2300: Duplicate identifier 'prototype'.
[0] node_modules/angular2/typings/es6-collections/es6-collections.d.ts(66,5): error TS2300: Duplicate identifier 'size'.
[0] node_modules/angular2/typings/es6-collections/es6-collections.d.ts(72,5): error TS2300: Duplicate identifier 'prototype'.
[0] node_modules/angular2/typings/es6-collections/es6-collections.d.ts(88,5): error TS2300: Duplicate identifier 'prototype'.
[0] node_modules/angular2/typings/es6-collections/es6-collections.d.ts(103,5): error TS2300: Duplicate identifier 'prototype'.
[0] node_modules/angular2/typings/es6-promise/es6-promise.d.ts(11,15): error TS2300: Duplicate identifier 'Promise'.
[0] node_modules/angular2/typings/es6-promise/es6-promise.d.ts(42,16): error TS2300: Duplicate identifier 'Promise'.
[0] public/js/acApp/app.component.ts(3,2): error TS2304: Cannot find name 'Component'.
[0] public/js/acApp/app.component.ts(8,2): error TS2304: Cannot find name 'View'.
[0] public/js/acApp/app.component.ts(21,16): error TS2304: Cannot find name 'RouterOutlet'.
[0] public/js/acApp/app.component.ts(23,2): error TS2304: Cannot find name 'RouteConfig'.
[0] public/js/acApp/app.component.ts(24,69): error TS2304: Cannot find name 'UserTimelineComponent'.
[0] typings/main/ambient/es6-shim/index.d.ts(11,5): error TS2300: Duplicate identifier 'done'.
[0] typings/main/ambient/es6-shim/index.d.ts(12,5): error TS2300: Duplicate identifier 'value'.
[0] typings/main/ambient/es6-shim/index.d.ts(477,11): error TS2300: Duplicate identifier 'Promise'.
[0] typings/main/ambient/es6-shim/index.d.ts(496,11): error TS2300: Duplicate identifier 'PromiseConstructor'.
[0] typings/main/ambient/es6-shim/index.d.ts(554,13): error TS2300: Duplicate identifier 'Promise'.
[0] typings/main/ambient/es6-shim/index.d.ts(563,5): error TS2300: Duplicate identifier 'size'.
[0] typings/main/ambient/es6-shim/index.d.ts(572,5): error TS2300: Duplicate identifier 'prototype'.
[0] typings/main/ambient/es6-shim/index.d.ts(583,5): error TS2300: Duplicate identifier 'size'.
[0] typings/main/ambient/es6-shim/index.d.ts(592,5): error TS2300: Duplicate identifier 'prototype'.
[0] typings/main/ambient/es6-shim/index.d.ts(607,5): error TS2300: Duplicate identifier 'prototype'.
[0] typings/main/ambient/es6-shim/index.d.ts(621,5): error TS2300: Duplicate identifier 'prototype'.
```

**UPDATE**

@Eric,

Tks. I remove the browser.d.ts from the angular2 folder. The duplication errors gone. Then, I have to remove  `///<reference path="node_modules/angular2/typings/browser.d.ts"/>`  , as it will cause file no found error. The remaining errors are ,

```
[0] public/js/acApp/app.component.ts(3,2): error TS2304: Cannot find name 'Component'.
[0] public/js/acApp/app.component.ts(8,2): error TS2304: Cannot find name 'View'.
[0] public/js/acApp/app.component.ts(21,16): error TS2304: Cannot find name 'RouterOutlet'.
[0] public/js/acApp/app.component.ts(23,2): error TS2304: Cannot find name 'RouteConfig'.
[0] public/js/acApp/app.component.ts(24,69): error TS2304: Cannot find name 'UserTimelineComponent'.
```

My folder structure is

```
-node_modules
-public
--js
---acApp
----main.ts
----app.component.js
```

The erros

Comment: Try removing `es6-promise` and `es6-collection` from typings `typings uninstall es6-promise --save` and `typings uninstall es6-collection --save`. es6-shim typings already have the typings of the other two.

Comment: You couldn'd do that I suggested above, those come from angular2's folder -_-, sorry. Remove the reference to `browser.d.ts` in angular2's folder and you should be fine.

Comment: No, it will cause other errors [0] node_modules/rxjs/Rx.d.ts(7,30): error TS2307: Cannot find module './subject/AsyncSubject'.
[0] node_modules/rxjs/Rx.d.ts(8,31): error TS2307: Cannot find module './subject/ReplaySubject'.
[0] node_modules/rxjs/Rx.d.ts(9,33): error TS2307: Cannot find module './subject/BehaviorSubject'.
[0] node_modules/rxjs/Rx.d.ts(12,28): error TS2307: Cannot find module './util/EmptyError'.
[0] node_modules/rxjs/Rx.d.ts(13,41): error TS2307: Cannot find module './util/ArgumentOutOfRangeError'.

Comment: You have something weird there. You shouldn't have seen those errors, you only need es6-shim typings. The error shows also things like `TS2304: Cannot find name 'Component'`, so you have something weird over there. Can you add your typings.json file?

Comment: {
  "ambientDependencies": {
    "es6-shim": "github:DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped/es6-shim/es6-shim.d.ts#7de6c3dd94feaeb21f20054b9f30d5dabc5efabd",
    "jasmine": "github:DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped/jasmine/jasmine.d.ts#7de6c3dd94feaeb21f20054b9f30d5dabc5efabd"
  }
}

Comment: There's something there, and I can't see it. You don't need at all browser.d.ts from angular2's folder if you have es6-shim. You could make a repo with your project to clone it and take a look at it.

Comment: You have mentioned target as ES5 in tsconfig.json but included ES6 Shim. This may be the reason ?

Comment: @Eric, pls see my update.

Comment: Your update makes me think that your setup is not reading the tsconfig.json.

Comment: Tks Eric, i find the causes. some of my paths are not configured correctly.

Comment: Eric, can u post ur reply as an answer?

Comment: How did you fix this ? I am facing similar issue

Comment: My tsconfig path ia wrong